# Prepared statement too slow

Tags: mariadb, php, mariadb-10.2

have an issue with MariaDB 10.2.12 running in aws rds (single master, no slave)

when I run prepared statement using a variable substitution

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM 
"select ...quite complex select from tenth of tables..
 and `subscribers`.`id` = ?
 group by `subscribers`.`id`
 limit 1";
SET @a = 77586744;
EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a;  
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

it takes 13 minutes to process (those tables have millions rows)

however, if I run the very same query without variableS:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT("select ...quite complex select from tenth of tables..
 and `subscribers`.`id` = ",77586744,"
 group by `subscribers`.`id`
 limit 1");
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1 ;  
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

it only needs 0.05s to run. The same time it takes if I not use PREPARE at all.

According to profiler output the long run involves several "converting HEAP to Aria" with reindexing and sorting it, which do not take place if no variable involved.

Why do this converting happen? it seems there is no lack in tmp/heap since the query runs in 0.05s, thus it's  "USING variable" changes something I don't know.

btw, we've faced the issue running application on PHP 7.1.20 with Laravel Framework 5.6.39,
so I cannot just rewrite a query to get rid of "USING variable" as it something that happens under the hood of PDO.

[image: 0.05s]
 [image: 769.20s]

UPD:
EXPLAIN for slow query
[image]

EXPLAIN for fast one
[image]

OK, explain differs, but it's kind of expected from profilier output. 
The thing I still  don't get is why it differs while the query stays the same.

Comment: This is not the first time I have seen @variables take longer than plain numbers.  Alas, I have not gotten to the bottom of the problem.  Meanwhile, notice how useless the profile is -- 99.9% of the time is in "Sending data" -- very common; very uninformative.

Comment: It may be tricky to get, but try to get the `EXPLAIN` from each case.  The slow one should be easy with MariaDB's way of `EXPLAINing` a currently running query.

Comment: moreover, it's unclear  "Sending data" where? besides, the query has "limit 1". I suspect it has smth to do with converting to Aria on-disk cache .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `subscriber_tag` a many:many mapping table?  Ditto for `segmentation_tag`?  If so, there may be several ways to speed up the use of such on *both* versions.  See [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

Comment: After all, only reformatting the query helped. 
still have no answer on why it chooses different  plans for the same query depending on variables in execute.